# Different IDEs give me different Results?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct STU{//Structure for transaction to make linked list
    unsigned int SID;
    unsigned int enteringgrade;
    unsigned int year;
    char University[32];
    char Student[32];

    struct STU *next;
}Node;

Node* addrecord(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, char*, char*, Node*);
void printrecord(Node *);

int main() {
    char str[4];
    Node *start = NULL;
    struct STU stu;

    while(strcmp(str, "END") != 0)
    {
    
        scanf("%s", str);
        if (strcmp(str, "Student") == 0) {

            scanf("%u %u %u %s %s", &stu.SID, &stu.enteringgrade, &stu.year, &stu.University, &stu.Student);
            start = addrecord(stu.SID, stu.enteringgrade, stu.year, stu.University, stu.Student, start);
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "print") == 0)
        {
            printf("Linked List Values: \n ");
            printrecord(start);

        }
    }
    free(start);
    return 0;
}

Node * addrecord(unsigned int SID, unsigned int grade, unsigned int year, char* uni, char* Student2, Node *start) {
    Node *newnode;
    int i = 0, k  = 0;
    newnode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newnode-> SID = SID;
    newnode-> enteringgrade = grade;
    newnode-> year = year;
    for(i = 0; uni[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        newnode -> University[i] = uni[i];
    }
    for(k = 0; Student2[k] != '\0'; k++)
    {
        newnode -> Student[k] = Student2[k];
    }
    newnode->next= start;
    start = newnode;
    return start;
}
void printrecord(Node *start) {
    Node *current = start;
    while ( current != NULL) {
        printf("%u %u %u %s %s", current->SID, current-> enteringgrade, current-> year, current-> University, current->Student);
        current  = current ->next;
    }
}
```

Input 1st IDE DevC++

Student 10 99 2022 Stanford Charlie Smith
print

Output 1st IDE DevC++

Linked List Values:

10 99 2022 Stanford CharlieOGONSERVER=\DESKTOP-1KFBc

Input 2nd IDE - Clion

Student 10 99 2022 Stanford Charlie Smith

print

Output 2nd IDE - Clion

Linked List Values:

0 4096 0   ε ε

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Here is my confusion. I am trying to create a code that allows the user to input a student with the fields ID, Grade, Year, University(character array) and Student(character array). My main IDE is Clion while devC++ is another I had initally, but it has less functions. I understand the jargon being output in my first IDE as it is memory allocated by the string, but not used. I cannot understand why my second IDE won't output anything at all. Any hints or thoughts would be helpful. My only thoughts is that it is a memory issue and DevC++ will use different memory?
Thanks!

Comment: this is a signal that you have undefined behavior in there somewhere

Comment: scanf for string you should not have &field, just field

Comment: `char str[4]` is uninitialized on the first iteration of `while(strcmp(str, "END") != 0)`.  That's not good!  It's officially 'undefined behaviour' (aka UB).  You then have `scanf("%s", str); if (strcmp(str, "Student") == 0) {` — and `str` is nowhere near big enough to hold `Student` so if you enter that string, you definitely have a buffer overflow and UB.  Make `str` bigger.  A lot bigger.  And don't use unconstrained `scanf()` for security reasons — use `char str[256];` and `if (scanf("%255s", str) != 1) { …report error and exit loop… }`.

Comment: Thanks everyone that fixed the issue it can be simpler then it seems sometimes...

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you're reading a string like "END", of length *n*, and you're allocating an array to read the string into, the size you want to be thinking about for the array is something like 10 × *n*.  Not *n* + 1 or *n* + 2, and certainly not *n*, let alone *n* - 1.  Trying to make the array *just big enough* is a totally [false economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_economy), and a frequent cause of bugs like the one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char str[4];` is an uninitialized buffer. The first iteration of `while(strcmp(str, "END") != 0)` will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by accessing the contents of `str` as if it were an initialized, null-terminated string.

`scanf("%s", str);` is [as dangerous as `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965), as it too does not limit the amount of data read in. This can *easily* overflow the buffer. When using `%s`, always include a *maximum field width*, which should be the size of the buffer being read into, minus 1 (leaving room for the null-terminating byte).

```
char buffer[128];
if (1 != scanf("%127s", buffer)
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read input.\n");
```

You can also see in the example above that the *address-of* operator (`&`) is not needed when passing an array to a matching `%s` specifier, as an array will *decay* to a pointer to its first element when passed to a function (`char [N]` becomes `char *`).

Additionally, the return value of `scanf` should always be checked to make sure the *expected number of conversions* took place before the corresponding values are used.

```
/* Incorrect */
scanf("%u %u %u %s %s", &stu.SID, &stu.enteringgrade, &stu.year, &stu.University, &stu.Student);

/* Correct */
if (5 != scanf("%u%u%u%31s%31s", &stu.SID, &stu.enteringgrade, &stu.year, stu.University, stu.Student))
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong!\n");
```

If you are going read the values directly into a structure, you could just as easily pass a pointer to that structure to `addrecord`, and copy the contents of the structure directly to the new node. You could even allocate the next node *before* reading input into it, to skip the copying step.

Also note, passing a pointer to the variable that points to the root node (`Node **`) lets you modify its value in `main` without having to rely on capturing the return value of `addrecord`.

This call to `free`

```
free(start);
```

only releases the memory of the root node, and none of the others. This is a memory leak. The program exits right after this, so it is fairly harmless, but something to watch out for.

Your program with some changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct STU {
    unsigned int SID;
    unsigned int enteringgrade;
    unsigned int year;
    char University[32];
    char Student[32];

    struct STU *next;
} Node;

void addrecord(Node **, Node *);
void printrecord(Node *);

int main(void)
{
    char str[256] = { 0 }; /* zero-initialize a generously sized buffer */
    Node stu = { 0 }; /* stay consistent with types */
    Node *root = NULL;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter command 'print', 'Student', or 'END': ");

        /* limit input length, and check the return value always */
        if (1 != scanf("%255s", str))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read command.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(str, "END") == 0)
            break;

        if (strcmp(str, "Student") == 0)
        {
            puts("ENTER: ID GRADE YEAR UNI STUDENT");
            /* Again, limit input, check return */
            if (5 != scanf("%u%u%u%31s%31s",
                        &stu.SID,
                        &stu.enteringgrade,
                        &stu.year,
                        stu.University,
                        stu.Student)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Bad format.\n");
                break;
            }

            addrecord(&root, &stu);
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "print") == 0)
        {
            puts("Linked List Values:");
            printrecord(root);
        } else
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid command.\n");
    }

    /* cleanup memory */
    while (root)
    {
        Node *next = root->next;
        free(root);
        root = next;
    }
}

void addrecord(Node **root, Node *from)
{
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    if (!node)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return;
    }

    memcpy(node, from, sizeof *node);

    node->next = *root;
    *root = node;
}
void printrecord(Node *current)
{
    while (current)
    {
        printf("%u %u %u %s %s\n",
                current->SID,
                current->enteringgrade,
                current->year,
                current->University,
                current->Student);
        current  = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

As [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173397/pm100) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399593/different-ides-give-me-different-results#comment127899875_72399593), if two IDEs disagree on the results of a program with the same data, it usually means that your program invokes undefined behaviour.

Looking at the code, `char str[4]` is uninitialized on the first iteration of `while(strcmp(str, "END") != 0)`. That's not good! It's officially 'undefined behaviour' (aka UB).

You then have `scanf("%s", str); if (strcmp(str, "Student") == 0) {` — and `str` is nowhere near big enough to hold `"Student"` so if you enter that string, you definitely have a buffer overflow and UB. Make `str` bigger. As [Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399593/different-ides-give-me-different-results/72400717#comment127900019_72399593), make it a lot bigger. And don't use unconstrained `scanf()` for security reasons — use something like:

```
char str[256] = "";

while(strcmp(str, "END") != 0)
{
    if (scanf("%255s", str) != 1)
    {
       …report error and exit loop (or program)…
    }
    …
}
```

You should always check the return value from input functions such as the `scanf()` family of functions.  And, as [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173397/pm100) also [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399593/different-ides-give-me-different-results/72400717#comment127899885_72399593), with `scanf()` et al, you should not place an `&` in front of character arrays.  These flaws are both apparent in your second `scanf()` call.